# redirect blog.mydomain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have a wordpress blog located at `blog.domain.com` and my regular website at `www.domain.com`, both hosted on an apache server.

my website root has it's own .htacess file, and my blog root has an .htaccess file.
virtual hosts are setup within the httpd.conf file

everything works as it should, what I'm trying to figure out is how to set-up the following redirects.

**main blog**

`blog.domain.com`     - Redirect to -      `www.domain.com/blog`

**all the blog articles**

`blog.domain.com/blog/article_name`       - redirect to - `www.domain.com/blog/article_name`

This needs to be seamless so we don't effect the permalinks already created within the blog

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using a Redirect rule in your `.htaccess` file on `blog.domain.com`:

```
Redirect 301 /blog http://www.domain.com/blog
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/blog/
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have access to your apache's `conf` files.

I would suggest you to do this:

create separate Virtual host block to `blog.domain.com`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName blog.domain.com

#other settings

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(blog)(/.*)? http://www.domain.com/$1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Actually just the above will suffice.

Comment: This doesn't redirect the requests to blog articles seamless like asked for in the question. `blog.domain.com/blog/article_name` will be redirected to `www.domain.com/blog/blog/article_name`.